# Write text to XPS document

Tags: c#, wpf, xps

I've got a WPF control with several text boxes on it. The number of controls is variable depending on what the user does in the program. What I need to do is take the text from the text boxes and write it to a XPS doc. What the question really boils down to is "How do I write lines of text to a XPS doc? Does anybody know of a library I can incorporate or what the best way to do this is?

Comment: Why not a FlowDocument?

Comment: The end result is to write the XPS doc to PDF, and I've already got a working framework in place to accomplish that. Although a flowdocument might be more along the lines of what I need, but I've never used it before. Should I look into that instead of XPS?

Comment: Maybe FlowDocument to XPS.   I don't know how to write directly to XPS.

Answer (score 0):

Here is simplest sample I saved to my OneNote some time ago (sorry I dont remember the source):

```
PrintDocumentImageableArea area = null;
XpsDocumentWriter wr = PrintQueue.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(ref area);

var text = new TextBlock() {Text = "Hello there"};
text.Margin = new Thickness(area.OriginWidth, area.OriginHeight, 0, 0);

Size outputSize = new Size(area.MediaSizeWidth, area.MediaSizeHeight);
text.Measure(outputSize);
text.Arrange(new Rect(outputSize));

text.UpdateLayout();

wr.Write(text);
```